# How to reverse a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to reverse the order of what the below method returns. For example if it 
returns:

```
1=ball, 2=save, 3=take 4=till
```

I want to reverse and return:

```
1=till, 2=take, 3=save, 4=ball
```

My method is:

```
  public Map<Integer, String> returnMapOfValues(ArrayList<String> wordsList) {
    int getFrequencyValue = 0;
    Set<String> uniqueSetWords = new HashSet<String>(wordsList);
    for (String temp : uniqueSetWords) {
        getFrequencyValue = Collections.frequency(wordsList, temp);
        //prints the Collection of words and they frequency, For testing only
        //System.out.println(temp + ":" + Collections.frequency(wordsList,
        //temp));
        map.put(getFrequencyValue, temp);
        getFrequencyValue = 0;
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: A `HashMap` doesn't have a predictable iteration order so you can't reverse it reliably either. Look into a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead.

Comment: I did read but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you tell us why you have a List input and need a Map output, and why that map needs to be ordered? Are you sure you don't want a List output in reverse order?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You're perfectly correct about the spec,  but in fact the current Java library implements HashMap with LinkedHashMap.  Just a random fact...

Comment: The map attaches the frequency values to the words. If you need other (value, word) pairs there is something wrong with the determination of the `getFrequencyValue`

Comment: @RickHanlonII I need to create a method that returns the rank of the most common word of a text file such as 1 for the most common, 2 for the second most common, etc. The method above method returns the frequency of each word but it returns in ASC order and I can't reverse it.

Comment: @Gene: could you clarify that?

Comment: Ah, can you add that explanation to the question? See my answer. A `TreeMap` is a Map ordered by the natural order of the keys.

Comment: @Gene `LinkedHashMap extends HashMap`

Comment: @MariuszS Sorry I was thinking of some other code I looked at in the Java library.  Bad memory...  Thanks for fixing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the below code I've written is useful for you as a reference:

```
public void reverseMap()
{
    NavigableMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
    LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> reverseMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1,"Apple");
    map.put(2,"Ball");
map.put(3,"Cat");
NavigableSet<Integer> keySet = map.navigableKeySet();
Iterator<Integer> iterator = keySet.descendingIterator();
Integer i;
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    i = iterator.next();
    reverseMap.put(i,map.get(i));
}
System.out.println(reverseMap);
}
```

Comment: you want the keys not to be reversed?

Comment: current output 1=ball, 2=save, 3=take 4=till

I want to reverse and return:

1=till, 2=take, 3=save, 4=ball

Comment: Fine, I have provided another answer recently with a changed code. Hope this would help you

Answer (score 2):

```
//map to arrange inizialized 
LinkedHashMap<String,object> mta;


//transforms into arrayList  hashmap keys and values

ArrayList<Object> valuesTMP=new ArrayList<Object>(mta.values());

ArrayList<String> keysTMP; 

keysTMP=new ArrayList<String>(mta.keySet());

//reverse 
Collections.reverse(valuesTMP);
Collections.reverse(keysTMP);

LinkedHashMap <String,Object> mtarranged=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

 int index=0;

  for( String key : keysTMP){

        mtarranged.put(key,valuesTMP.get(index));
        index++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, we need to know how you're iterating the Map since Maps don't have entry order. However, you may try using a `TreeMap` which has the method `descendingMap`:

```
public Map<Integer, String> returnMapOfValues(ArrayList<String> wordsList) {
    TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    int getFrequencyValue = 0;

    Set<String> uniqueSetWords = new HashSet<String>(wordsList);
    for (String temp : uniqueSetWords) {
        getFrequencyValue = Collections.frequency(wordsList, temp);
        //prints the Collection of words and they frequency, For testing only
        //System.out.println(temp + ":" + Collections.frequency(wordsList,
        //temp));
        map.put(getFrequencyValue, temp);
        getFrequencyValue = 0;
    }

    return map.descendingMap();
}
```

Edit: From your comment, your intent is more clear. A [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) will help you with your goal because it is a Map ordered by the natural order of the keys.

Comment: Thanks for the above code, it reverses the map but the key are still the same. This was my expected output 1=till, 2=take, 3=save, 4=ball any ideas? and thanks for your help.

Comment: I used just a System.out System.out.println("return test method: " + wordObj.test(wordObj.wordsList));

Comment: We need more code than that... The way you are printing out the elements is what needs to change, not the structure of the Map data.

Comment: I am not using anything else. the only thing extra is a method to get the file and the method you posted + a main method to print what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to the code. Please check if this is OK for you now.

```
public void reverseMap()
{
NavigableMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> reverseMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1,"Apple");
map.put(2,"Ball");
map.put(3,"Cat");
NavigableSet<Integer> keySet = map.navigableKeySet();
Iterator<Integer> forwardIterator = keySet.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> reverseIterator = keySet.descendingIterator();
Integer i;
Integer j;
while(forwardIterator.hasNext())
{
    i = forwardIterator.next();
    j = reverseIterator.next();
    reverseMap.put(i,map.get(j));
}
System.out.println(reverseMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code and Let me know Which is suitable for you ...

```
        int iterationValue = 0;
        List<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
        stringList.add("ball");
        stringList.add("save");
        stringList.add("tick");

        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
        for (String temp : stringList) {
            map.put(iterationValue++, temp);
        }
        // Input MAP
        System.out.println(map); // {0=ball, 1=save, 2=tick}

        Collections.reverse(stringList);
        iterationValue = 0;
        for (String temp : stringList) {
            map.put(iterationValue++, temp);
        }
        // Output MAP
        System.out.println(map); // {0=tick, 1=save, 2=ball}
```